# solution for error message "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays" not working

Tags: angular, ngfor

In my angular app I want to show a list of products the user can select.

So in my html file, I wrote the following code:

```
<section fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <mat-selection-list #products>
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let product of products">
            {{product.name}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
</section>
```

In the .ts file, I have the following code:

```
  products;


  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAll();
  }


  private loadAll(): Promise<any> {
    this.products = [];
    return this.productService.getAll()
    .toPromise()
    .then((result) => {
        result.forEach(product => {
          this.products.push(product);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {     
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

I'm getting the following error message:

Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

The thing is: products is(!) an array.

Still, I'm getting this error message as if this.products were in fact not an array.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already having an array, so no need to convert to array again,

```
  result.forEach(product => {
          this.products.push(product);
  });
  this.products = Array.of(this.products); //remove this line
```

Comment: I thought so too ... I added this line just to  make absolutely sure I got an array ... I didn't include the line before .... wanted to get rid of the error this way .... but the error remains exactly the same: "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"

Comment: can you post the result of console.log(JSON.stirngify(this.products));

Comment: [{"$class":"org.comp.app.Product","company":"Nike","logItems":[],"id":"2","name":"test"}]

Comment: I removed the line as you told me ... the output above is the output you get after removing the line "this.products = Array.of(this.products);" .... I keep getting the same error message telling me that "ngFor" can only be used for arrays

Comment: the JSON you posted is a valid one and it should work

Comment: but it doesn't ... can it have something to do with the fact that this component is a dialog component. (When clicking on a button on the website, a dialog-window (see https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) opens, which is supposed to display a list of products)

Comment: can you produce a stackblitz

Comment: @Sajeetharan 
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let product of products">
            {{product.name}}
</mat-list-option>
here mat-list-option is a component, right? why the loop is here? is it ok to write like this?
why not <mat-list-option></mat-list-option> and in its html 
a div should iterate the loop like this 
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
            {{product.name}}
</div>
please correct me is I am wrong..

Comment: suddenly it works now (without me changing the code) ... weirdest thing I've ever seen

Comment: may be for cache  @Tommy

Comment: @tommy as I mentioned your json is valid after the changes , should be definitely because of cache, mark if the answer helped